# set CultureInfo based on MsoLanguageID in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, ms-word, localization, internationalization, ms-office

In my add-in for Microsoft Word, I have noticed that `System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture` (or `CurrentUICulture`) will give me the current system language, which doesn't necessarily reflect the Word interface language. I am finding that this can be retrieved using `Application.LanguageSettings.LanguageID` in this manner:

```vb
Dim Application As Word.Application = Globals.{MyAddIn}.Application
Dim lang As Office.MsoLanguageID = Application.LanguageSettings.LanguageID(Office.MsoAppLanguageID.msoLanguageIDUI)
```

(changing out {MyAddIn} for the actual add-in namespace).

This will give the MsoLanguageID enumeration (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/office.msolanguageid). Is there any way of then setting the `CurrentUICulture` based on the `MsoLanguageID` without doing it manually with say, a `Select Case` that has a hundred or so cases (as many as there are values in the MsoLanguageID enum?)

Comment: Take a look at the [LCID Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.cultureinfo.lcid?view=netcore-3.1)

Comment: Related to this, there is a `CultureInfo` ctor that takes an LCID argument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to get UI localization automatically applied. You can store localized strings in the resources of your add-in and apply them on the fly depending on the Office UI language chosen.

```
public void AddinStartup()
{    
    if (this.OfficeApp != null)
        SwitchLanguage(GetLanguageID(this.OfficeApp));
}
 
private int GetLanguageID(dynamic app)
{
    Office.LanguageSettings languageSettings = app.LanguageSettings;
    if (languageSettings != null)
        try
        {
            return languageSettings.LanguageID[Office.MsoAppLanguageID.msoLanguageIDUI];
        }
        finally 
        {
            Marshal.ReleaseComObject(languageSettings); 
        }
    return 0;
}
 
private void SwitchLanguage(int officeLanguageID)
{
    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture =
        new System.Globalization.CultureInfo(officeLanguageID);
    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture =
        new System.Globalization.CultureInfo(officeLanguageID);
 
    ComponentResourceManager resources =
        new ComponentResourceManager(typeof(AddinModule));
    resources.ApplyResources(this.MyRibbonTab, "MyRibbonTab");
    resources.ApplyResources(this.MyRibbonGroup, "MyRibbonGroup");
    resources.ApplyResources(this.MyRibbonButton, "MyRibbonButton");
    resources.ApplyResources(this, "$this");
}
```